# Error #1452 when altering mySQL table to add foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

Trying to help an intern with her project.  She wants to add foreign keys to an existing table but this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `document` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `document_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cle_author`) 
  REFERENCES `author` (`id_author`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

gives this error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wrc_mysql`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-30e4_7000d'>, CONSTRAINT `document_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cle_author`) REFERENCES `author` (`id_author`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Schema are like so

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id_document` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abstract` text,
  `number_of_pages` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_surrey_citation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_citation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `library_of_congress` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cross_citation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questions` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cle_author` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_document`),
  KEY `cle_author` (`cle_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22591 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `id_author` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender_office` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_author`),
  KEY `author_name` (`author_name`,`sender_office`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22591 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Does your data in the `document` table agree with that in the `author` table? Does every `cle_author` value in the `document` table have a corresponding entry in the `author` table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fai)

Comment: Hey,  you are correct.  This query shows bad references:  SELECT cle_author FROM document doc 
LEFT JOIN author a ON doc.cle_author=a.id_author 
WHERE a.id_author IS NULL;

Comment: I'll put it as a proper answer then. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have inconsistent data between your two tables. This error means that you have a `cle_author` value in your `document` table that doesn't have a corresponding entry in the `author` table. Since the `cle_author` value is going to be set up as a foreign key, each value for that field must have a corresponding entry in the `author` table's `id_author` field.

Comment: if the data in the tables is not important : TRY THIS -> delete all the records in your tables and then try add the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Per this page:  [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fai)

checked intern's data with

SELECT cle_author FROM document doc 
LEFT JOIN author a ON doc.cle_author=a.id_author 
WHERE a.id_author IS NULL;

And found ALL of her cle_author data is bogus and does not hold valid references to id_author values.