# Transaction fails due to foreign key Mysql error 1452

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction that inserts data into three tables. This transaction has been failing, but I have found, that if I remove the relation in phpmyadmin, the transaction completes successfully.

To re-add the relation I need to remove all the data in the tables!

The three tables consit of: 'User_Account' (which has a primary key) ,
 'Item' which also has a primary key

'User_Account' and 'Item' are related by a joining table called 'User_Item' with a compound key. The images for the item are referenced by a table called 'Image_Items' which is referenced by the foreign key from the 'Item' table.

I cannot see why this should not work? As only one table seems to use the key at one time?Any suggestions as to why this could be happening? Or what I am doing wrong!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_item` (
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key from account',
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key from item',
  `status` enum('active','deleted') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Is item active or been deleted',
  `date_added` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date item was added',
  UNIQUE KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`item_id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key for item',
  `item_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'title name of the item',
     `catagory`enum('accessories','jackets','coats','footwear','legwear','jeanswear','dresses','s     hirts','tops','t-shirts','knitwear','skirts','shorts') NOT NULL COMMENT 'item  catagory',
  `brand` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'brand of product',
  `store` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'store the item was purchased',
  `location` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'location the item was purchased',
  `month`  enum('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October'      ,'November','December') NOT NULL COMMENT 'month the item was purchased',
  `year` int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'year the item was purchased',
  `details` varchar(500) NOT NULL COMMENT 'details about the item description',
  `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'date item created',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='holds data about the item'     AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_account` (
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unique account ID',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key from user table',
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'users username default emailaddress',
  `account_status` enum('active','online','frozen','offline','hidden') NOT NULL COMMENT    'status of account, online offline frozen hidden active',
  `account_type` enum('admin','user') NOT NULL COMMENT 'type of account user or admin',
  `account_created` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'date the account was created',
  `account_modified` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'date account was last modified',
  `salt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'encryption',
  `password` char(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'users password',
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`username`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='details of the users account'      AUTO_INCREMENT=56 ;
```

And the query

```
$mysql = "INSERT INTO user_item(account_id,item_id,status,date_added)
            VALUES('$accountId','$itemId','$status','$date')";
            $mysqlResult = $this->conn->query($mysql)or   die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't show your query, so we can't help you. But if you do `show innodb status` immediately after the failed transaction, it'll have more details about WHY you got that error buried about 1/2 way down the output. look for "last foreign key error" or something like that.

Comment: Hi Marc, here is the query -> $mysql = "INSERT INTO user_item(account_id,item_id,status,date_added)
    VALUES('$accountId','$itemId','$status','$date')";
    $mysqlResult = $this->conn->query($mysql)or die(mysql_error());

Comment: And what did the user_item table look like BEFORE you removed the FK definitions? When you get that error, it means you're inserting a record for which no matching 'parent' record exists

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa)

Comment: This is a test database, as I am new to SQL! The user_item table remains the same, I just removed the relation as part of fault finding as to why the transaction failed. Currently items, user_items return an empty set, user_account has data but with no reference to item

Comment: I have just removed all data from all tables, however this problem continues? I am researching show innodb status suggested by Marc :)

Comment: I don't get it, the title is "Transaction fails due to foreign key Mysql error 1452", but there are 0 FK constraints on any of the tables in question.

Comment: Well I'm glad you are using a test database. One rule you should keep in mind is NEVER remove a foreign key when it tells you it is being violated. This error means your code is wrong not that the foreign key shouldn't exist. Basically what you did was insert into table with a foreign key where the data didn't exist in the orginal table. You need to track down what data you tried to insert and see why it would violate the key. But you need to insert to the users first, insert to the item next, and then insert to the useritem. One possibility is that you are sending a '' instead of a null

Comment: Thanks HLGEM I will have a look at this now and post an update!

Comment: @Mike Purcell I went back to my code and var_dump everything again and found I was passing a NULL value to the attribute, thanks for pointing out FK constraints ;). Its strange because when I ran the query in phpadmin it returned error 1452. Goes to show my not always be the query!! Thanks Mike HLGEM, Marc, CanSpice for your help much appreciated.