# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails webERp

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I use WebERP in my 1and1 account, when I migrate my database to another 1and1 database I get this error:
SQL query:

```
-- 
-- Constraints for table `chartdetails`
-- 
ALTER TABLE `chartdetails` ADD CONSTRAINT `chartdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY ( `accountcode` )      
REFERENCES `chartmaster` ( `accountcode` ) ,
ADD CONSTRAINT `chartdetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY ( `period` ) REFERENCES `periods` ( `periodno` )
```

MySQL said:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbxxxxxxxxx/#sql-    376_3fa4f12`, CONSTRAINT `chartdetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`period`) REFERENCES `periods` (`periodno`))
```

But the original file just work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Error when i migrate. I resolved this error in 3 ways. You can resolve your error on any one of them or an all. This happens because of no data insret query happens before you alter.
• Put Alter table queries on last of all other queries.
• Twice check for the presence of data where the primary key is present
• Install fresh DB later insert in hierarchical order like chart master first and later chart detail insert queries.

**Note:** DB wont allow you to delete or insert when you try to change db queries. Keep backups of DB before making any changes.