# MySQL Foreign key constraint - Error 1452 - Cannot add or update child row

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1452

I've used the other posts on this topic, but I'm having no luck.

Here's the code I execute:

```
UPDATE tblOrderItems SET `ItemID` = 0004 WHERE `OrderNum`= 203 AND `OrderItemID` = 26
```

Here's my error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cai0066`.`tblOrderItems`, CONSTRAINT `ItemID` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `tblCatalogItems` (`ItemID`))
```

Notes:

1. It happens when I either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` into `tblOrderItems`.
2. `tblCatalogItems` **does** have an `ItemID` of `0004`. See: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuuOp.png)

Here are the create statements generated by MySQL Workbench:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tblCatalogItems` (
  `ItemID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ItemName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Wholesale` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost5-10` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost11-19` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost20` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Retail` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tblItemCosts` (
  `Cost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `VendorID_idx` (`VendorID`),
  KEY `ItemID_idx` (`ItemID`),
  CONSTRAINT `VendorID` FOREIGN KEY (`VendorID`) REFERENCES `tblVendors` (`VendorID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tblOrderItems` (
  `OrderItemID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrderNum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PayPalTxnID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UnitPrice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemStatus` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrackingNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippingCost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalPrice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderItemID`,`OrderNum`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PayPalTxnID_UNIQUE` (`PayPalTxnID`),
  KEY `PayPalTxnID_idx` (`PayPalTxnID`),
  KEY `UnitPrice_idx` (`ItemID`),
  KEY `OrderNum_idx` (`OrderNum`),
  CONSTRAINT `ItemID` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `tblCatalogItems` (`ItemID`),
  CONSTRAINT `OrderNum` FOREIGN KEY (`OrderNum`) REFERENCES `tblOrders` (`OrderNum`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `UnitPrice` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `tblCatalogItems` (`ItemID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7678 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tblOrderItemStatus` (
  `OrderItemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrderDate` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DesignProofSent` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubmittedToProduction` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InProduction` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Shipped` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderItemID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `OrderItemID_UNIQUE` (`OrderItemID`),
  KEY `OrderItemID_idx` (`OrderItemID`),
  CONSTRAINT `OrderItemID` FOREIGN KEY (`OrderItemID`) REFERENCES `tblOrderItems` (`OrderItemID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tblOrders` (
  `OrderNum` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PayPalTxnID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderStatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'New',
  `RushFlag` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `ShipName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipEmail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipAddress1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipAddress2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipCity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipState` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipZip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippingCharge` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalCost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderNum`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PayPalTxnID_UNIQUE` (`PayPalTxnID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=346 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `tblVendors` (
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VendorName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VendorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

I tried the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa) relevant post, but there were no results. This is a new database that hasn't actually been used yet; I've just filled it with fake data. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing the `UPDATE` on `tblCatalogItems`?

Comment: I will edit my post to include this: It happens when I either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` into `tblOrderItems`. I do not want to create new catalog items, I want to pull items from the catalog and into orders. I hope that clears some things up.

Comment: You have `SET ItemID = 0004` but `ItemID` is varchar. Try `SET ItemID = '0004'`, if such an item exists in the parent table.

Comment: This is all the problem was. I can't believe it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a foreign key constraint on `tblOrderItems` that *its `ItemID` needs to reference an `ItemID` that already exists in `tblCatalogItems`*.

```
CONSTRAINT `ItemID` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `tblCatalogItems` (`ItemID`),
```

The message only means that you're trying to update `tblOrderItems` to reference the item in `tblCatalogItems` with `ItemID`= 0004, but that item does not exist.

Since `ItemID` is a varchar, you probably want to quote the `0004` or it may be converted to an int `4` before conversion to varchar. That may be your problem if the row with `ItemID` = 0004 actually exists.

```
UPDATE tblOrderItems SET `ItemID` = '0004' WHERE `OrderNum`= 203 AND `OrderItemID` = 26
```

Comment: I just threw off my glasses because I've been working on this all day and it was a type issue. Thank you. Some of the `ItemID`s have chars in them, so I'll just have to quote them all. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table data I can't be sure, but I'm guessing it's because there is no record in `tblCatalogItems` with an `ItemID` of '0004'.

Also, you probably need to quote the `0004` in your update statement since the column is defined as character (`varchar(10)`) not number (`int`).

There is a foreign key relationship defined between `tblCatalogItems.ItemId` and `tblOrderItems.ItemId` which means that any row in `tblOrderItems` can only have a value for `ItemId` that matches an `ItemId` found in `tblCatalogItems`.

You would therefore need to insert a record into 'tblCatalogItems' with an `ItemId` of '0004' first, before running your update on `tblOrderItems`

Alternatively you need to change the `SET ItemID =` clause in your update to set a value that matches to an `ItemId` value that actually exists in the `tblCatalogItems` table

Answer (score 0):

The data type needs to match on both sides of your foreign key constraint. Here you have a `varchar(50)` referring a `varchar(10)`, which isn't allowed.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblCatalogItems` (
  `ItemID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

...

CREATE TABLE `tblOrderItems` (
  `ItemID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT `UnitPrice` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `tblCatalogItems` (`ItemID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7678 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```