# mysql error 1452: can not add or update child rows, a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, django

I went through a several QA's on stackoverflow in order to solve this for me but could not find. I did try all the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa) but it does not seem to help.

Whenever i try to update a record in table with a foreign key, I get the following error.

```
Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row
```

what other factors might be causing this ? I'm using django 1.4, if that matters.

#### PS:

I tried the answers in the questions i mentioned and i always get an empty result as follows:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
```

Comment: It's because `FOREIGN KEY ('address_id')` is expected to have a corresponding value that you have inserted to `('id')`. `FOREIGN KEY ('address_id') REFERENCES 'marketing_prospectivecandidateaddress' ('id')`

Comment: it value does exist in `marketing_prospectivecandidateaddress` table

Comment: Yeah, but you missed to put value for the reference table. Post the command codes that you use for updating the table

Comment: i simply use django models save method, you can find the code to the save method here : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L489

Comment: well actually you are correct while updating the record, for some reason the value of address is not being passed in the request.

Comment: put your codes for update and we will try to find a solutionn

Answer (score 1):

If you insert or update a row on the first table the referenced address ID must exists on the second Table. 

You can also add the following code to the foreign key constraint:

> ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

that means all modifications will be cascade to the child table

Comment: the `address_id` of the record i am trying to update does exist in the second table.