# I'm crazy trying to solve an error, but i can't. With mysql. Foreign key error while doing INSERT INTO.

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

In mysql, when i try to do:

INSERT INTO `Comandes_Productes`(`Id_Comanda`, `Id_Producte`) VALUES ('60', '10009') --> (or others values)

for example, i get this error message: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cafeteria`.`comandes_productes`, CONSTRAINT `comandes_productes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Producte`) REFERENCES `comandes` (`Id_Comanda`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I try to do a lot of solutions that are proposed the next link, but, too i didn't solve the error.

[Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa)

I will get you the code, to see if i have an error in it.

**CREATE TABLES:**

```
CREATE TABLE Comandes (  
    Id_Comanda INTEGER(9) AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    Quantitat INTEGER(4),  
    Id_Proveidor INTEGER(9) NOT NULL,  
    Data DATE,  
PRIMARY KEY (Id_Comanda),  
FOREIGN KEY (Id_Proveidor) REFERENCES Proveidors(Id_Proveidor) ON UPDATE CASCADE    
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;  

CREATE TABLE Productes (  
    Id_Producte INTEGER(9) AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    Marca VARCHAR(15),  
    Nom_Producte VARCHAR(30),  
    Preu_Producte FLOAT(4,2),  
    Quantitat INTEGER(4),  
    Descripcio VARCHAR(50),  
Id_Proveidor INTEGER(9),  
PRIMARY KEY (Id_Producte)  
) AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;  


CREATE TABLE Comandes_Productes (  
        Id_Comanda INTEGER(9),  
        Id_Producte INTEGER(9),  
        PRIMARY KEY (Id_Producte, Id_Comanda),  
FOREIGN KEY (Id_Producte) REFERENCES Productes (Id_Producte) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (Id_Producte) REFERENCES Comandes (Id_Comanda) ON UPDATE CASCADE    
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;
```

And yes, i already have the foreing keys values in the tables "Comandes" and "Productes". All tables are with InnoDB, too i try to delete all database and create other time, but.. nothing... I see the specifications of the tables and too are all the same.

In what i fails? Please help me! I can't continue with my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem with your `Comandes_Productes` table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Id_Producte) REFERENCES Comandes (Id_Comanda) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

probably it should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (Id_Comanda) REFERENCES Comandes (Id_Comanda) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Also, I am not much into MySQL, but probably you shoud not use single quotes when entering numerical values.

Comment: OMG... I lost a lot of time, and it's... a very very stupid error... :(. Thank you a lot, YK1