# MySQL error 1452 Cannot add or update child row

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

Beginner at MySQL.

Have a project (written by someone else) running.
Got new database for it, put it in MySQL.
Now am getting error

```
1452 Cannot add or update child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('proj'.'access_logs', CONSTRAINT 'access_logs_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'users' ('id'))
```

`access_logs` has `access_logs_ibfk_1`, `users` has `users_ibfk_1,-4,-5,-6` - 4 of them

Have looked this up and tried:

- making sure no `accesslogs user_id` with no matching `users id`,
- collations are same (utf8_general_ci)
- engines are same (InnoDB)
- types are same (`user_id` is INT(11) UN, `id` is `INT(11) UN PK AI)`
- make sure program works ok with previous data (it's in CakePHP 1.3) and it works

What can be going wrong and how can it be fixed ?

Comment: What is the exact SQL that is being run? `file_put_contents("/some/tempfile",$sql);` immediately before the failing command should save it to a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa)

Answer (score 0):

You have a field in table `access_logs` that accepts a `user_id`, that number **must** exist first in table `users` in field `id`.

Foreign Key (or FK in short) is constraint on the data you insert to a table, it means the value you insert into table A must **first** exist in some other table. Which other table and which field exactly in that table depends on how you defined the FK.

I would read about the common constraints SQL based servers have (Primary Key, Not Null, Unique and Foreign keys )

Comment: Thank you for writing back.Made sure no