# Error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Table CARGO

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "hibernatecurso"."cargo";
CREATE TABLE  "hibernatecurso"."cargo" (
  "idcargo" int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "funcao" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("idcargo")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

Table EMPREGADO

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "hibernatecurso"."empregado";
CREATE TABLE  "hibernatecurso"."empregado" (
  "idempregado" int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "nome" varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  "cargo" varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY ("idempregado"),
  KEY "idx_cargo" ("cargo")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

create index in empregado

```
ALTER TABLE `hibernatecurso`.`empregado` ADD INDEX `idx_cargo`(`cargo`);
```

---

Create FK in empregado

```
ALTER TABLE `hibernatecurso`.`empregado` DROP INDEX `idx_cargo`,
 ADD INDEX `idx_cargo`(`cargo`),
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_empregado_cargo` FOREIGN KEY `FK_empregado_cargo` (`cargo`)
    REFERENCES `cargo` (`funcao`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

in this part....

Error while executing query.

```
ALTER TABLE `hibernatecurso`.`empregado` DROP INDEX `idx_cargo`,
 ADD INDEX `idx_cargo`(`cargo`),
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_empregado_cargo` FOREIGN KEY `FK_empregado_cargo` (`cargo`)
    REFERENCES `cargo` (`funcao`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

> MySQL Error Number 1215
>   Cannot add foreign key constraint

What is causing the error?

Comment: add proper code blocks to your queries in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa?rq=1

Comment: do you have any data in the tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maybe have hard time reading, but I don't see any index on `cargo.funcao`. This is very probably missing:

```
ALTER TABLE `hibernatecurso`.`cargo` ADD INDEX `idx_funcao`(`funcao`);
```

---

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. 
>   However, in the referenced table, there must be an
>   index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in
>   the same order.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue and I fixed it by making sure that collation and types matched in both FK and the parent PK.