# Error 1215. Cannot add a Foreign Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I have two tables. `notas_cabecera` and `vehiculos`.

These are my tables structures:

`notas_cabecera` table:
[image: notas_cabecera table]

`vehiculos` table:

[image: vehiculos table]

but when I add a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE notas_cabecera 
ADD CONSTRAINT chapa_vehiculo_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (chapa_vehiculo)
REFERENCES vehiculos(chapa_vehiculo);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

What does this mean?

Comment: It's not the same case. Because the data types are the same varchar(8) for both notas_cabecera.chapa_vehiculo and vehiculo.chapa_vehiculo

Comment: Maybe check the **Related** list on the right side of the page for other similar problems and you may find your answer that way.

Comment: You are Right. The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081252/error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint?rq=1

The vehiculos table didn't have an index on chapa_vehiculo. Thanks