# foreign key in php my admin to php code

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I made two tables in PHPmyadmin, I received this error when I tried to transfer the data into my database:

> Error:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`poolfootball`.`choix`, CONSTRAINT `choix_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_member`) REFERENCES `log_in` (`id_member`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I think the only error is the data transfer from table log_in to choix. I have no problem with the table log_in. I already got my log_in table and the data transfer into the database works well.  When I try to do the the same thing for table choix, I get this error. I'm trying to make this for entertainment. I will use this website with my friends only. Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: you are trying to insert or update a record that would be orphaned. there's nothing to fix with your table structure. it is you doing inserts/updates incorrectly, or in the wrong order.

Comment: I just want the data id_member from table log_in goes to table choix. The primary key of table log_in is id_member and the primary key of choix is id_member and week.

Comment: I change the relation to restricted for update and delete and it still not work.

Comment: Do you have an exemple of php code that could help me with that. I have an insert into choix the data from the table that must be enter but I still don't know how to enter the id_member from the table log_in into the code. I thought it will do it automatically when I configure the table in phpmyadmin.