# MySQL: Cannot add a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I recently moved some tables to a new database. I left the foreign keys of these tables pointing to tables in the old DB.

I then created new versions of the referenced tables. I tried first to *modify* the FK so that they will point to the new references. That didn't work, so I dropped all old FKs and tried to create new ones. The first phase went through without a hitch. The second phase though failed with each and every table, *in  the same way!* The response was always like:

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ml`.`#sql-d04_2`, CONSTRAINT `FK_excoeff_secID` FOREIGN KEY (`SecurityID`) REFERENCES `securities` (`SecurityID`))
```

The failure appears *immediately* and doesn't seem to relate to actual data. In the error message, as you can see, the place where the table name is usually located is now filled with a strange string. And no matter what the referring table is, the error contains the *same* string.

All that happend in the "Alter table" part of the MySQL WorkBench, but also as a regular SQL query.

Where did I go wrong???

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Comment: No, it is not. The key differences are 1) the strange string where the table name is. It must mean something, and 2) it is the _same_ "table name" for all tables that I try to add a FK to them. 3) All table data _was_ governed by an equivalent foreign-key. There are no conflicts in the data!

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Peter Brawly, [in the MySQL forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,654189,654189#msg-654189) was very helpful. His answer was:

1. The "strange string" was simply the name of a temporary table used internally
2. The reason for the failure is probably the old fashion one - a violation of the referential integrity in the data. And he was right!
3. And the SQL query to detect the culprit(s) is:

   SELECT DISTINCT c.ID
   FROM child_table AS c
   LEFT JOIN parent_table AS p USING(ID)
   WHERE p.ID IS NULL;