# Insert statement using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table enquiry (
    eqid integer not null auto_increment primary key,
    question varchar(500),
    cusID integer(100),
    tpid integer(100),
    staffid integer(100)
 );

alter table enquiry add foreign key(tpid) references tourpackage (tpid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

alter table enquiry add foreign key(staffid) references staff (staffid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

alter table enquiry add foreign key(cusID) references customer (cusID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

---

```
insert into enquiry
    values (0, "What is the minimum travel group size?",0,0,0);

insert into enquiry
    values (0, "Can we return at a later date?",0,0,0);

insert into enquiry
    values (0, "I would like to use my KrisFlyer miles points to redeem an air ticket. Is it possible?",0,0,0);
```

I have problem inserting my enquiry values in. Error state that cannot add or update child row.

Comment: Show that actual error message please

Comment: @MatBailie Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`enquiry`, CONSTRAINT `enquiry_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tpid`) REFERENCES `tourpackage` (`tpid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inserts should probably look like this:

```
insert into enquiry (question)
    values ('What is the minimum travel group size?');
```

You should not be inserting into the auto-incremented primary key.  Let the database do the work for you there.

I am guessing that the "0" values for the other columns are intended to mean "no reference".  If so, let the database just insert `NULL`s.  Otherwise, you need to be sure that each reference table has a "0" value.

Comment: Duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails/21660862

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Whats the (question) for?

Comment: How come it doesnt not retrieve from other table the cusID, tpid, etc?

Comment: Cherlyn you can visit the link i have shared in the comment and check for Rahul's answer your doubts will be cleared