# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (prj_tvto.activities, CONSTRAINT activities_school_id_foreign FOREIGN
>   KEY (school_id) REFERENCES schools (id)) (SQL: insert into activities
>   (school_id, cluster_id, group_id, updated_at, created_at) values (0,
>   2, 3, 2018-08-14 05:02:28, 2018-08-14 05:02:28))

In Controller

```
public function store(Request $request, SchoolsList $schoolsList)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $activity = new Activity();
        $activity->school_id = intval($request->school_id);
        $activity->cluster_id = $request->cluster_id;
        $activity->group_id = $request->group_id;
        $activity->save();
        return response()->json(['data_activity' => $request->all(), 'id' => $activity->id]);
    }
}
```

And Ajax

```
        var school_id = {school_id: data_school.id} ;
        console.trace(school_id);
```

I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: Also post you php code of query, about what you are executing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: Looking at your insert query, the `school_id` that is being passed is *0*. Are you sure you have a school with the id of 0?

Comment: I did edit in my form and how to solve it? thanks