# Making foreign key to unique index column in mysql

Tags: mysql

### Products

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS `PRODUCTS` (
   `ID` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `COMPANY_ID` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `PRODUCT_CODE` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
   `PRODUCT_NAME` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   `UNIT_TYPE` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
   UNIQUE INDEX UNIQUE_COMAPNY_PRODUCT_CODE (`COMPANY_ID`, `PRODUCT_CODE`),
   CONSTRAINT `PRODUCT_COMPANY_ID_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPANY_ID`) REFERENCES `companies` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

and i want to make a foreign key to the upper 'PRODUCT_CODE' ......
here is my code

```
ALTER TABLE services
ADD COLUMN `PRODUCT_CODE` VARCHAR(5),
// ADD foreign `PRODUCT_CODE` that refrences to `PRODUCT_CODE` in PRODUCTS table
```

So how to do the commented line above in mysql ??

Answer (score 2):

The column referenced in a foreign key *may* be either a Primary Key or Unique. You need to first add an index on `PRODUCT_CODE`. I have taken it as `UNIQUE`

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS ADD UNIQUE INDEX (PRODUCT_CODE);
```

Then, you can use [`ALTER TABLE .. ADD FOREIGN KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE services
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_CODE) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_CODE);
```

Combining this to your existing `ALTER TABLE` query, a single query would look as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE services
ADD COLUMN `PRODUCT_CODE` VARCHAR(5),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_CODE) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_CODE);
```

If you already have some data in the `services` table, which has certain `PRODUCT_CODE` value, which do not exist in the `PRODUCTS` table. You will get the following error:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

In that case, you will need to fix the data in the tables. You may check this answer for the tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099922/2469308

Comment: it gives me this error `Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index in the referenced table
`

Comment: @TitoTito You will need to add index on the parent table

Comment: Please have a look at the edited version of the question

Comment: So how to do that in mysql ? i am beginner :)

Comment: it gives me `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
`

Comment: @TitoTito then in that case, you have some rows in the `services` table which have some `PRODUCT_CODE` values, which do not exist in the `PRODUCTS` table. You need to fix those first. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099922/2469308