# "Cannot add or update a child row" mysql

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys

I am continuously getting this flag:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb4653`.`stars`, CONSTRAINT `fk_stars_movie` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`movieID`) REFERENCES `movie` (`id`))

when I try to insert the data into the table

These are the tables

```
movie(id, title, relYear, category, runTime, director,
studioName, description, rating)
actor(aID, fName, surname, gender)
stars(movieID, actorID)
movGenre(movieID, genre)
```

I think it could have something to do with the fact that its not the only **movieID** as it is the only one I am having issues with. It is definitely indexed

I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE stars
(movieID INTEGER,
actorID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CONSTRAINT fk_stars_movie FOREIGN KEY (movieID) REFERENCES movie(ID)
);
```

as well as manually making it the foreign key in the relation view. It is also the same data type as its primary key so that's not the issue either.

```
CREATE TABLE movie
(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(100), 
 relYear INTEGER, 
 category VARCHAR(5), 
 runTime INTEGER, 
 director VARCHAR(50), 
 studioName VARCHAR(100), 
 description VARCHAR(500), 
 rating DECIMAL(10,2)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: I'm curious to see the `CREATE TABLE movie` script and the insert query you're using

Comment: You can not `update` or `insert` in child table without it parents.

Comment: @Cid I've edited the question to show the CREATE TABLE  movie query, for the insert query it's :INSERT INTO stars VALUES and then copied and pasted values which worked for every other table

Comment: well, this is the `VALUE` part that is relevant

Answer (score 0):

set foreign_key_checks=0;

Your insert query goes here...

set foreign_key_checks=1;