# Why am I getting error code 1452 cannot add or update child row

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a foreign key to a table that has a composite key. I was able to add the foreign key for the first column but not the second.

I have searched stackoverflow, reading all of the similar questions. I've searched the internet. I have checked the parent tables against the child table and the column definitions appear to be the same. I've checked the spelling of the column names. I have used another alter statement that worked for another foreign key. I'm at a loss.

Table: orderdetails

```
Columns:
OrderID int(11) PK 
ProductID int(11) PK
```

Table: products

```
Columns:
productid int(11) AI PK
```

```
ALTER TABLE orderdetails
     ADD CONSTRAINT fk_od_prodid
     FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES products(productid);
```

I expected to create the foreign key but got error code 1452 instead.

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa)

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs when one of the rows exists already in the child table `orderdetails`, that is not also in the parent table `products`.

You can ignore the error and force it temporarily by using

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE orderdetails
     ADD CONSTRAINT fk_od_prodid
     FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES products(productid);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Alternatively to find the offending records use

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orderdetails AS o 
LEFT JOIN products AS p 
ON p.productid = o.ProductID 
WHERE p.productid IS NULL;
```

And to remove the offending records 
*(only affects the `orderdetails` table, leaving `products` unmodified.)*

```
DELETE o
FROM orderdetails AS o
LEFT JOIN products AS p
ON p.productid = o.ProductID
WHERE p.productid IS NULL;
```

After removing the offending records, your `ALTER` statement should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong. there were two values in the child table that were not in the parent table. I deleted those records and my error went away.