# Laravel Create Order using API

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, laravel-5

I'm building an API for e-commerce app

now, i get stuck in creating order

i have the following Migrations

Orders

```
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('order_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->enum('status', ['pending','processing','completed','decline'])->default('pending');
        $table->float('grand_total');
        $table->integer('item_count');
        $table->boolean('is_paid')->default(false);
        $table->enum('payment_method', ['cash_on_delivery'])->default('cash_on_delivery');
        $table->string('notes')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Order_items

```
        Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');

        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('quantity');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Products

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('img');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('desc');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this is Models Relationship

Order Model

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Medicine::class, 'order_item','order_id','product_id')->withPivot('quantity','price');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $order = new Order();
    $order->order_number = uniqid('ORD.');
    $order->user_id = 1;
    $order->item_count = 2;
    $order->grand_total = 20;
    $order->save();

    return response(['message'=>'successful']);
}
```

Now, i can add Orders successfully .

but how to add items from JSON Request

for example by posting JSON Data from Postman

any ideas?

**UDPATE**

JSON Post Request

```
    [
    {
        "id":1,
        "product_id":4018,
     "price":20,
     "quantity":1
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "product_id":4019,
     "price":50,
     "quantity":3
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "product_id":4020,
     "price":45,
     "quantity":2
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to create new rows within `order_items` with created `order`?

Comment: @GhanuBha yes, that is exactly what i want but i want to do this using json request

Comment: It is very usefull if you put your json request data here then we can help you.

Comment: @GhanuBha i update the code

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/lG0zY04llQxHX6lWFK_hlg?language=php You can do this way.

Comment: @GhanuBha this way work perfectly but how to get data from json request
instead of static json data

Comment: @GhanuBha Now, I notice a bug with this way 
when i change some date in json the code doesn't work correctly and it give me "successful" but there is nothing in database

Comment: Have you used DB transaction rollback?

Comment: @GhanuBha yes i do i used the code you sent

Comment: Then in the last line inside try block there is DB::commit(); ?

Comment: @GhanuBha yes that's right

Comment: Even items are not being saved in database ??

Comment: There is spell correction in `DB::commit()` there is not one time `m` two times `m` exist.

Comment: @GhanuBha if i changed the json data in $items for example "product_id" and run the function again it give me the success message but the data isn't inserted to the Database

Comment: i already fixed the spelling before. This is not our problem

Comment: Comment `DB::beginTransaction()`, `DB::rollback()`, `DB::commit()` line and try.

Comment: @GhanuBha Now the Order is created successfully but the items isn't and still give me the success message

Comment: write `dd($e);` inside catch function. and check what is the error.

Comment: @GhanuBha       SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ecom`.`order_items`, CONSTRAINT `order_items_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `order_items` (`order_id`, `product_id`, `price`, `quantity`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (72, 2025, 20, 1, 2020-07-02 14:25:43, 2020-07-02 14:25:43))

Comment: there is product id issue, may be `id` is not available in product table. Please check with product id.

Comment: @GhanuBha No it's available!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57213523/6361075 try this answer and check you items table

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are storing hardcorded instead of that use $request values. Like below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

$order = new Order();
$order->order_number = uniqid('ORD.');
$order->user_id = $request->user_id;
$order->item_count = $request->item_count;
$order->grand_total = $request->grand_total;
$order->save();

return response(['message'=>'successful']);
}
```

In your postman pass value like

```
{
user_id:1;
item_count:2;
grand_total:20;
}
```

Comment: i know this is just for test 
what i wanna to do is add items to order

Comment: what do you mean by add items to order? Adding new one to order like above is working way.