# @PostMaping insert null in dbd

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i am doing a rest application and i have problems when i use @PostMaping
I have 2 classes with models of the first TblEmployees and 2 classes of TblDepartments they are connected on foreign key = "dbID"

when i insert:

```
 {
     "empName": "days",
     "empActive": 0,
     "dbID": 15,
     "dep_name": "sso"
 }
```

gives an error SQL Error: 1452

here is my code:

```
TblEmployees має поля empName, empActive,dbID
TblEmployees має поля dbID, dep_name
EmployessServise

    public TblEmployees add_Employees(TblEmployees tblEmployees){
    return  repo.save(tblEmployees);

EmployesController

@PostMapping("/add_Emp")
public TblEmployees add_emp(@RequestBody TblEmployees tblEmployees){
    return  service.add_Employees(tblEmployees);

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class TblEmployees {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int emp_id;
    private String empName;
    private Boolean empActive;
    private Integer dbID;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dbid",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private TblDepartments departments;
---getter setter

@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class TblDepartments {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dbID")
    private Integer dbID;
    private String dep_name;


    public TblDepartments(){
    }

---getter setter
```

Comment: I assume that you're using MySQL database, then the error code 1452 means *Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails*. So please make sure that `dbID` does EXISTS in another table.

Comment: dbID are in both tables

Answer (score 0):

You SQL Error code shows that the foreign key you are sending in you request body (which is *dbID*) does not exist in the *departments* table.

Double check you departments table. Make sure you are sending the correct foreign key (dbId-One that exists in table of departments).
You can find more info on the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)