# How to use the user ID as a foreign key?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, mysql-error-1452

I have two tables, 'users' and 'posts', looking like this:

```
users:
- id
- username
- password
...

posts:
- id
- user_id (foreign key referencing users.id)
- text
```

Basically, a user has multiple posts (blog-type posts). Now, I'm trying to create a new post as a logged in user, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I've done:

```
// 'User' model
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array('Post');

    ...

// 'Post' model
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Post';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );

// In PostsController
public function create()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->Post->create();
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)
        {
            // Success
        }
    }
}

// In the post view
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('action' => 'create')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <?php echo __("Write a post"); ?>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Post')); ?>
```

If I write a post and click 'Post', I get an integrity constraint violation:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
constraint fails (`yams`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `user_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Am I missing something here? It looks like the user id is not saved to the model.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, the database error also prints out the SQL query which is clearly wrong:

```
INSERT INTO `yams`.`posts` (`text`) VALUES ('this is a test post.')
```

There's no ID whatsoever...

Comment: See if it helps . http://stackoverflow.com/a/16805528/1003917

Comment: your $belongsTo variable in the Post model doesn't need to specify the foreignKey - CakePHP will automatically look for a column named "user_id" if you don't specify anything else

Comment: Have you allowed null in user_id field in posts table?

Comment: @AngularAddict no, I haven't. I want every post to reference to the user who posted it.

Comment: Ok. Is your posts id field primary and auto increment?

Comment: Try this: $this->Post->User->saveAll($this->request->data);

Comment: @AngularAddict Yes, both. I edited the post and added the false SQL query it is trying to execute. It's missing the ID altogether.

Comment: Your `Post` models needs to be aware of `user_id`. So you can add it to `$this->request-data` and then add it to the form or manually add it to data array before saving.

Comment: @skywalker How do I get the user ID in the Post model? I assume I can do it in beforeSave() function?

Comment: Post debug($this->request->data); in you question.

Comment: Are you using `Auth` or posts are made by unregistered users?

Comment: I think your data is not in correct form..

Comment: @skywalker I'm using Auth, only users that are logged in can create posts.

Comment: OK I will write you an answer.

Comment: What does debug($this->request->data) output?

Comment: @AngularAddict This: array( 'Post' => array( 'text' => 'this is a test post.') )

Comment: Yep. This is the problem. There is no user id in your post data :D Just do before save call add this line: $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

Comment: Lol. Lost my reps by adding this as comment :D

Comment: @AngularAddict have a comment upvote then. :)

Comment: Cheers, not so sad anymore :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
// In PostsController
public function create()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Post->create();
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)
        {
        // Success
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just copying the book here, i have not used cakePHP at all!

According to the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html then a 'hasMany' relationship should look similar to:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Recipe' => array(
            'className' => 'Recipe',
            'conditions' => array('Recipe.approved' => '1'),
            'order' => 'Recipe.created DESC'
        )
    );
}
```

You have:

public $hasMany = array('Post');

Should there be mention of a classname in yours?
i.e.

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post'
           )
       );
```

With this then the ORM can work out how the classes relate and what to fill in at run time.