# MySQL error 1452 - can't add records to table

Tags: mysql

So I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa) and I've tried two of the solutions but it didn't work for me = I have hard time understanding this error. I'm kind of new to databases and MySQL in general.

You can find my database right [here](https://github.com/comatory/lostmac-SQL-DB). I populate the tables with scripts in `cmdspace_lostmac queries/` folder.

What I did:

1. Designed DB via ERR diagram via MySQL Workbench
2. Exported the DB as `.sql` script (file `cmdspace_lostmac.sql`)
3. Ran the script on my local server on my machine (no errors)
4. Ran all the other scripts except `model.sql` (no errors so far)
5. Then it gives me error 1452

The `model.sql` file contains this script:

```
# desktops
insert into model(category_id, product_name, product_identifier, year_released, size_id, color_id, CPU_id, GPU_id, ext_link)
values(2, 'iMac Retina 5K Late 2014', 'iMac15,1', 2014, 18, 1, 43, 41, 'http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.5-27-inch-aluminum-retina-5k-late-2014-specs.html');

# laptops 
insert into model(category_id, product_name, product_identifier, year_released, size_id, color_id, CPU_id, GPU_id, ext_link)
values(1, 'Macbook Air Mid 2012', 'MacBookAir5,2', 2012, 9, 1, 138, 35, 'http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.8-13-mid-2012-specs.html');

# iphones
insert into model(category_id, product_name, product_identifier, year_released, color_id, size_id, drive_id, ext_link)
values (3, 'iPhone 6 Plus', 'iPhone7,1', 2014, 4, 4, 5, 'http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-6-plus-a1522-5.5-inch-gsm-north-america-specs.html');
```

Note: When I run `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, run the script and then set back to `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` I can do this. But obviously I would need to disable the check everytime I need to update database. That's obviously bad design.

Comment: Please show the query that gives you this error.

Comment: It is the one in `model.sql` file: