# Foreign key constraint fails with Insert Into Select in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new to SQL, and I'm trying to upload data to my tables. For this I have special tables where I upload the data from a CSV file, and then, from this table, I am trying to copy the data to the final table.

But now I have a problem with an intermediate table where I have uploaded my data. The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `_work_has_person` (
  `work_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `primary_contribution_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`work_id`,`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to copy the data in

```
CREATE TABLE `work_has_person` (
  `work_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `primary_contribution_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`work_id`,`person_id`),
  KEY `fk_work_has_person_person1_idx` (`person_id`),
  KEY `fk_work_has_person_work1_idx` (`work_id`),
  KEY `fk_work_has_person_primary_contribution1_idx` (`primary_contribution_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_work_has_person_person1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_work_has_person_primary_contribution1` FOREIGN KEY (`primary_contribution_id`) REFERENCES `primary_contribution` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_work_has_person_work1` FOREIGN KEY (`work_id`) REFERENCES `work` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Which is an intermediate table between:

```
CREATE TABLE `work` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_work` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtitle_work` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_work` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unix_date_work` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sinopsis` text,
  `ref_bne` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_alt` longtext,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_work_language1_idx` (`language_id`),
  KEY `title_work` (`title_work`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_work_language1` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24610 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img_person` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `born_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unix_born_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_born_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_born_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `death_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unix_death_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_death_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_death_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `biography` longtext,
  `ref_bne` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_alt` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9159 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But everytime I try to run

```
INSERT INTO work_has_person (work_id, person_id, primary_contribution_id)
SELECT work_id, person_id, primary_contribution_id
FROM _work_has_person;
```

It says

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cdu93hfg93r`.
`work_has_person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_work_has_person_person1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) 
REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I am pretty sure that the tables has the neccesary data, but, ¿is there a way to know which data fails? I have seen [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa):  but don't understand exactly how to use it here.

A.

Comment: Use something like `select person_id from work_has_person minus select id from person` to figure out unrecognized persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively easy to find out what data is causing the conflict: get all `person_id`s from `_work_has_person` that are not in the `persons` table. You can achieve this via an outer join and filtering for `person.id` is null in the where clause.

```
select * from `_work_has_person` whp
left join person p on whp.person_id=p.id
where p.id is null
```

You can actually remove such data from the results being inserted by including the reverse criterion into the `select` part of your `insert` query (an inner join):

```
INSERT INTO work_has_person (work_id, person_id, primary_contribution_id)
SELECT whp.work_id, whp.person_id, whp.primary_contribution_id
FROM _work_has_person whp
INNER join person p on whp.person_id=p.id
```

Comment: Thank-you! And not only for the query, but for the explaining as well. Now I understand what I have to do in this situations (and this is a very common one). I was trying to do `SELECT * FROM _work_has_person a LEFT JOIN person b ON a.person_id=b.person_id WHERE p.id IS NULL`, which is quite stupid…