# Error Code 1452 When attempting to Alter Table Constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

```
ALTER TABLE `charter`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `charter_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CHAR_DESTINATION`) 
  REFERENCES `airport` (`AIRPORT_CODE`);
```

I am attempting to create this relationship:

[image]

[Charter and Airport ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTNkv.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE `antonellacammarota` (
  `CUS_CODE` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CUS_CODE`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`CUS_CODE`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`CUS_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into customer values (10076, "Cammarota", "Antonella", "T", "805", "555-1212", 0);

insert into antonellacammarota(select cus_code from customer where cus_lname = 'Cammarota');

--
-- Table structure for table `airport`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `airport` (
  `AIRPORT_CODE` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AIRPORT_NAME` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_ADDRESS` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_CITY` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_STATE` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_ZIP` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_COUNTRY` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_AREACODE` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AIRPORT_PHONE` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AIRPORT_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Constraints for table `airport`
--
ALTER TABLE `charter`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `charter_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CHAR_DESTINATION`) REFERENCES `airport` (`AIRPORT_CODE`);


--
-- Dumping data for table `airport`
--

INSERT INTO `airport` (`AIRPORT_CODE`, `AIRPORT_NAME`, `AIRPORT_ADDRESS`, `AIRPORT_CITY`, `AIRPORT_STATE`, 
`AIRPORT_ZIP`, `AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, `AIRPORT_AREACODE`, `AIRPORT_PHONE`) VALUES
('ATL', 'Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta Int', '6000 N Terminal Pkwy.', 'Atlanta', 'GA', '30320', 'US', '808', '897-1910'),
('BNA', 'Nashville Int', '1 Terminal Dr.', 'Nashville', 'TN', '37214', 'US', '615', '275-1675'),
('GNV', 'Gainesville Regional', '3880 NE 39th Ave.', 'Gainesville', 'FL', '32609', 'US', '352', '373-0249'),
('MOB', 'Mobile Regional', '8400 Airport Blvd.', 'Mobile', 'AL', '36608', 'US', '800', '357-5373'),
('MOY', 'Monterrey', '', 'Monterrey', '', '', 'Columbia', '', ''),
('STL', 'St. Louis Lambert Int', '10701 Lambert International Blvd.', 'St. Louis', 'MO', '63145', 'US', '314', '426-8000'),
('TYS', 'McGhee Tyson', '2055 Alcoa Hwy', 'Alcoa', 'TN', '37701', 'US', '865', '345-3000');
```

Comment: You likely have bad data in the system that you must handle before you can add the constraint. Likely the FK refers to a PK that no longer exists or never did.

Comment: I considered that as an option; I have deleted the schema three times now.

Comment: Please list the content of your `charter` table. `SELECT CHAR_TRIP, CHAR_DESTINATION FROM charter;`

Comment: 10001 ATL
10002 BNA
10003 GNV
10004 STL
10005 ATL
10006 STL
10007 GNV
10008 TYS
10009 GNV
10010 ATL
10011 BNA
10012 MOB
10013 TYS
10014 ATL
10015 GNV
10016 MQY
10017 STL
10018 TYS

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow that deal with this error. The most common problem is what @xQbert mentioned: some data in your child table has no matching data in the parent table. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to find out what entry is screwing things up

```
SELECT CHAR_TRIP, CHAR_DESTINATION 
FROM charter
WHERE CHAR_DESTINATION NOT IN (
SELECT AIRPORT_CODE FROM airport);
```

Comment: 10016 MQY
 was returned; I thought MQY was MOY

Comment: @AntonellaCammarota remember to check this as an accepted answer if it solved the issue for you.