# Error Code: 1452 cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created a table member_history_logs.

```
        CREATE TABLE `member_history_logs` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `element_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `status` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
          `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
          `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          KEY `status` (`status`),
          KEY `element_id` (`element_id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There is another table named members consisting of

```
    'id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
    'description', 'varchar(100)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
    'short_name', 'varchar(1)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

I want to perform an alter table

alter table member_history_logs add  foreign key (element_id) references members (id);

I am getting the following error:

```
Error Code:1452 cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails mysql
```

Please correct me. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have resolved it. Table member_history_logs must be **empty** only then you will be able to run **Alter Table** command.

Comment: One option is that `member_history_logs` table is empty. Another option is that all values in `element_id` column of the `member_history_logs` table exist in `members` table. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5vGfGmd6kQBbMzSwzGSooQ/0) (error) and [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iLv32XpvLdUY2F8AuuAmff/0).